# Paypal Developer - Cannot create Sandbox Business Account plus Error Messages

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to set up a Paypal Dev App by first creating the two (personal and business) Sandbox Accounts.  However it only displays the `-facilitator..` business account with the following error message when I click on its Profile

> We experienced some issues on our end while creating this Sandbox account.  Please delete it and try again.

Unfortunately the check-box next to the account is grayed out and I cannot delete it.  When I go to create an APP it says:

> There are no sandbox business accounts associated, please create one and try again.

So I have also tried creating NEW Sandbox business accounts.  When I click save I see that it has updated the Total Records by one, but it still shows the same amount of accounts (the facilitator and any personal accounts I created).

Anyone have any idea on what I can/should do?  Can I re-create the whole developer account somehow?

[image: Paypal Issue]

Comment: Getting this as well and I basically can't create a REST API app b/c of it. Any solution since Oct 15? Paypal is the worst company I've had to deal with in my life and this is aggravating me.

Comment: I am having the exact same issues in July 2015. Any news how you solved the issue?

Comment: Same issue here. I'm not able to create any test app. Wondering if PayPal is the right payment provider to work with :/

Comment: I am also facing same issue since last 3 days. If anybody is able to find solution please let us know.

Comment: Just to add that it's already 2016 and I still have same problem. I have been deleting sandbox accounts for last hour and creating new ones but still getting same error.

Comment: @KoviNET Well, I'm not even able to delete these accounts that I have..

Comment: The problem seems to have reappeared. Here's a Paypal forum thread about it: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Selling/API-Sandbox-Problems/td-p/978414?profile.language=en

Comment: I finally got it to work by setting that the account was not bank verified and by giving it a $100 balance when creating the business account. Not sure if those steps were important or if the bug just went away, but it worked for me after trying several times to create an account with other options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this randomly all weekend and never really figured out what caused it... It did work for me though when I went back to it a day or two later.

gave me a really weird feeling about using paypal at all to be honest.  good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same for me since 3 days. Getting pretty nuts about it.  Yesterday the problem was different an error message was displaying on the page as : `We’re sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.`

Today when I logged in I found all the test account that I have created yesterday but with no money on the account. So I have deleted them and when I recreate I get the same behavior mentionned above.

This is the notification for the first issue, didnt' find new one but guess they are working on it.

https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details?eventId=5775

Comment: It seems pretty odd. They still have the same issues in 2016 LOL

Comment: Got the same thing, errors everywhere, cannot do anything to add payment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, and threads all over the internet going back to 2013 which is even more frustrating. Here is what solved it; you need to fill in ALL the fields even the ones that say 'Optional' (First Name, Last Name, Funding, Notes). Then it works fine. Just someone on their end who never did use-case testing I think. In any event I am now making test accounts without issue.