# Paypal give me a Required scope missing error when creating billing plan

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm now putting a paypal subscription button on my site using python `paypal-sdk`

To subscribe payment, I'm following these steps.

1. create billing plan
2. activate it
3. create billing agreement
4. execute it.

But creating billing plan has been failed and sent me `REQUIRED SCOPE MISSING` error. I copied billing plan arguments from paypal official dev site. So I don't think I missed something on request.

Here is my code to create billing plan

```
billing_plan = paypalrestsdk.BillingPlan({
  "name": "T-Shirt of the Month Club Plan",
  "description": "Monthly plan for getting the t-shirt of the month.",
  "type": "fixed",
  "payment_definitions": [
    {
      "name": "Trial Plan",
      "type": "TRIAL",
      "frequency_interval": "1",
      "frequency": "MONTH",
      "cycles": "1",
      "amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "9.99"
      },
      "charge_models": [
        {
          "type": "TAX",
          "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "value": "1.65"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "SHIPPING",
          "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "value": "9.99"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Standard Plan",
      "type": "REGULAR",
      "frequency_interval": "1",
      "frequency": "MONTH",
      "cycles": "11",
      "amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "19.99"
      },
      "charge_models": [
        {
          "type": "TAX",
          "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "value": "2.47"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "SHIPPING",
          "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "value": "9.99"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "merchant_preferences": {
    "setup_fee": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "1"
    },
    "cancel_url": "http://www.cancel.com",
    "return_url": "http://www.return.com",
    "max_fail_attempts": "0",
    "auto_bill_amount": "YES",
    "initial_fail_amount_action": "CONTINUE"
  }
})
if billing_plan.create():
  return billing_plan.id
```

and here is my configuration for paypal

```
PAYPAL_CONF = {
  'mode': 'sandbox',
  'client_id': CLIENT_ID_IN_SANDBOX_ACCOUNT,
  'client_secret': SECRET_IN_SANDBOX_ACCOUNT,
}

paypalrestsdk.configure(settings.PAYPAL_CONF)
```

and error message

```
ForbiddenAccess: Failed. Response status: 403. Response message: Forbidden. Error message: {"name":"REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING","message":"Access token does not have required scope","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING","debug_id":"bf845229ca125"}
```

I've searched a few of articles, but no luck.

EDIT: I've tried about app settings, but the problem is different.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for your comment. I've already checked sandbox app setting. But there is no setting for billing plan. just billing agreement. FYI: enabling billing agreement gave me this "We are sorry something went wrong while saving application please try again... " for entire day. Do you think it cause because of that billing agreement setting is disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My co-worker solved this for me. Actually I'm using default sandbox facilitator app which paypal created for me. You can access those app like this. (*it doesn't show apps on Dashboard)

sandbox > accounts > account-facilitator > profile > API credentials tab > apps

But It wasn't working. So he made a new app using Dashboard > My Apps & credencials > create app(sandbox) and replaced client id and secret of new one.

It works like magic.

ps. When I was struggling with it, I found @tamak's comment. "gave me a really weird feeling about using paypal at all to be honest." in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26393932/4476298

SO TRUE.

Comment: hey i'm having same problem in my sanbox app settings there is no biling plan just agreement, how did you made it to work?